# Using log4j Logger in a project add via Maven

Tags: java, log4j

I do have a project A that uses a fixed Framework (having the Framework's projects as Maven dependencies)  which has a Logger using log4j 1.2.17.

No I want to use another project B which I add via Maven dependencies to project A. This project will have it's own Logger inside and I want it to send it's logs to the console and the same file as project A.
I am allowed to edit the logger configuration in project B, but not in project A, since I need logs from the framework too.

It looks like log4j goes with the first implemented Logger, which is the one from the framework and does not give der Logger from project B access to the console. It works if I let it log to a different file, but that is not what I need.

Does anyone have an idea for this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Project A should not provide a fixed logger configuration. It should be bundled as a library to be used through a dependency and let the final application (here project B) to configure the loggers.

Doing that, the project B which depends on project A can choose and configure where and how the emitted logs for both projects should go.